# Why is `rake -T` run with RAILS_ENV test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rake

## Problem

Some rake tasks provided by gems did not show up with `rake -T` or `rake -T -A` (rake > 10).

### Discovery

Gems listed only in the `:development` group are not loaded when `rake -T` is run. I found that this is likely because `ENV['RAILS_ENV']` is being set to `test` when running `rake -T`.

However, `rake` tasks are invoked in the development environment. Why is `rake -T` setting the `RAILS_ENV` to `test`?

Comment: It doesn't do that for me. I need to say `rake RAILS_ENV=test` to see test tasks. Are you sure RAILS_ENV isn't set to test in your shell?

Comment: Oh, and there seems to be a typo in your rake version. The current version is 1.11.2.

Comment: `echo $RAILS_ENV` just gives me a blank line so I don't believe it is set to anything. Is there another way I could check if it or something else is setting it? I did make a new rails app before submitting and was able to reproduce the error but there could just be something funky with my system.

Comment: That's how I'd check RAILS_ENV, and it doesn't sound like that't the problem. Making a new app was a good thing to try too. I guess you only changed the Gemfile. It miiiiiight help to post that.

Comment: Regarding version, the one the project is on is `0.9.2.2` at the moment. I just upgraded to `11.1.2` to see if the `-A` option would work since it is not available in `0.9.2.2`. I'll update the question to have the correct version.

Comment: You could put `puts ENV['RAILS_ENV']` at the top of the implementation of `rake -T`, in `display_tasks_and_comments` in rake/application.rb, to see if that envariable has been set by the time it reached that code.

Comment: @DaveSchweisguth I can confirm that it is "test" at the top of `Application#display_tasks_and_comments`.

Comment: Weird! If RAILS_ENV isn't set in the shell environment where you run rake, but it is set by the time rake gets around to printing your tasks, something in between must be setting it. You'll have to go through the rake executables and your project and find it.

Comment: I had the same experince today. On our staging and production servers the require packages in the test group, when just running `rake -T`. If I add run `RAILS_ENV=development rake -T` it does not require the test gems. - We have `Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env)` in the top of the `application.rb`

Comment: @JesperGrannLaursen I suggest writing a new question with all relevant information and commenting here with a pointer to it.

Comment: ran into the same issue today with a clean rails installtion. tasks are shown for main group and things grouped as test. not development

Comment: its quite strange that rake db:migrate runs in development and not test but rake --tasks runs in test oOo